# How to quantify the similarity/difference between groups of selected features?

Tags: statistical-significance, feature-selection, group-differences, similarities

Since I have a imbalanced data to deal with, I randomly down-sample the negative data to reach balanced data for following feature selection and classification. To test feature's robustness to different samples, the above process is repeated 30 times and I want to measure the difference among groups of selected features in each one of 30 rounds. Higher similarity claims the robustness of the selected features to difference samples.

How could I do this?

EDIT:
I have a thought of measuring "indirectly": Refitting the selected features in each of 30 samples using the whole dataset and observe the performance distribution, e.g., variance. For example, if I have m out of M features selected in the i-th sample, I can get a performance by using only m features but on the whole dataset. By doing so, 30 performances using different selected features but the same dataset can be obtained and by observing the variance of the performance distribution we can probably claim the following: **Higher variance represents bad robustness of selected features because they are quite different among samples; lower variance might represent rather good robustness on the other hand.**
But the problem is, low variance doesn't necessarily claim the selected features are similar across samples, because they are derived under the subsets of the dataset.

Comment: It is not good statistical practice to down-sample.  Any method that requires down-sampling is dubious.  Most people make the mistake of down-sampling because they do not understand [proper accuracy scoring rules](https://www.fharrell.com/post/class-damage).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about an absolute metric for this, but a nice way to think about it could be with [Hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance). For each of the 30 samples, create a vector of indicators of whether a feature was included or not. For example, if there are possible features 0,1,2,3,4, and only features 1 and 2 were selected in a round, the vector would be [0 1 1 0 0]. So you get 30 different vectors:

```
[0 1 1 0 0]
[1 0 1 0 0]
...
[0 1 1 0 0]
```

You can compute a similarity metric between these vectors by counting the number of matches and dividing by the length. For example,

```
sim([0 1 1 0 0], [1 0 1 0 0]) = 3/5 = 0.6
```

So a quick way to compute an overall similarity score would be to compute all pairwise similarities and compute the mean or median. A higher mean similarity score would mean a more robust feature selection method across samples.

Comment: Thanks! This sounds like a direct way of measuring similarity, I also come up with a relatively "indirect" way and added in the OP, correct me if wrong.

Comment: I think your idea of an "indirect" measure seems pretty useful, at least from a predictive performance perspective (and maybe that's all you really care about, after all!). It might be worth trying to implement the Hamming distance solution to see how the two ideas differ in practice.